# location.href and Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: javascript, php, session, header

I understand that there can be no output before setting the headers, and I believed that I am following that rule. I have a php page a.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ...
    echo "<button id=\"searchForTeamsButton\">Search For Teams</button><br>";
    ...
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("searchForTeamsButton").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "b.php";
    };
</script>
```

and php page b.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

Upon clicking that button, I am receiving the classic headers already sent error. I am lead to believe that the location.href is not calling a new page "b.php", which allows for new headers. My true question here is what is the proper protocol for redirecting to new pages with links/ buttons? Perhaps location.href is the correct (and perhaps only) way, and perhaps my error is actually on b.php.

I appreciate any information here.

Thanks :)

Brent

Comment: @adeneo I am starting the session on two different pages.. When does the session carry over to the next page vs not? I feel like checking is the session is already set is leaving starting the session up to chance, vs knowing when you need to restart the session or not.

Comment: I was thinking ajax, so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Check that there is no whitespace or any other characters before your opening PHP tag in `b.php`.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara that did the trick. I TRY to not post here unless it's needed. 9/10 times it's something foolish. thanks :)